# Charging devices with different max voltages

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, charging, circuit-protection

I have a project that requires me to make a portable power pack that can be charged up and then power different devices. The product needs to have two USB charging ports and hold around 7Ah.

The problem I have is that the devices it will charge vary in minimum/max current and voltage and I would like to not damage the devices it is charging. What is the best way to do this as the only way I would know is to state the rails, yet I cant list all the devices it could charge so should I go for a general voltage and current.

Also what are some of the important circuits I should be looking to make sure the device has to make it more safe. Any answers are appreciated

Comment: If you're charging devices via USB ports you just give them 5V and let them take the current they need.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a USB 2.x connector then you should supply only 5 V.
Configuration of the D+/D- lines can advise of the peripheral charging current required. If you don't use these lines then you will simply provide the current defined by the peripheral.

If you are using a USB 3.x connector then you can negotiate the output voltage based on the connected peripheral device.

[This answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/159552/how-does-a-usb-c-port-provide-the-power-to-charge-laptops) provides a starting point for your research. Short answer.... read the USB 3 spec.