# 12V from Mi power bank 3

Tags: voltage-regulator, powerbanks

I have an [Mi 18W 10000mAh powerbank 3](https://www.mi.com/global/10000mAh-mi-18w-fast-charge-power-bank-3) which I want to use for my project. I need 12 volt output. Although this powerbank supports 12V output, this feature is probably proprietary. A [PD decoy module](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000124529027.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.1b7a4c4dVDgiBI) does not give 12V. I need power for a 12V LED strip in a portable photobox.

Is there some solution (decoy module or something) to make the Mi powerbank produce a 12 volt output? I didn't find anything.

Comment: If you are using that decoy module, make sure you soldered the jumper to tell it to ask for 12V.  Better yet, also test the decoy module works against a different power supply.  I'm not seeing anything in the spec page that says the power bank provides 12V Output when it is not being charged by a 12V supply.

Comment: https://www.mi.com/global/10000mAh-mi-18w-fast-charge-power-bank-3/specs

Comment: that's the spec I was looking at.  It says "Output ports USB-A x 2" and later says "USB-A x2 5.1V2.6A" which could mean that the only only outputs on the USB A are 5.1V.  The line that says "USB-A x1:
5.1V2.4A / 9V2.1A/ 12V1.5A (18W MAX)" has some fishy stuff.  Either it's to cover their butts for failing to protect a USB-A port from 12V during charging via a 12V charger, or they meant USB-C in which case they would likely use some form of PD as it's part of the USB-C specs

Comment: Even if they had meant USB-C, they did not mention it as an output port so the spec makes no clear claims about an ability to output 12V.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a step up DC-DC converter that has a 5V input, which would be far easier to do than trying to spoof a proprietary technology like PD or QC, which as the module you mentioned is not reliable or completely legal.

Comment: I looking for strightforward solution with maximum efficiety, withou DC-DC converter. Maybe for Mi powerbank not exist solution with some like decoy module.

Comment: Correct. it will not exist. The protocol likely uses a hardware identification chip that is proprietary hardware by the manufacturer, and is usually protected by IP agreements.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Based on the spec you referenced, I believe the premise that "Although this powerbank support 12V output" is flawed.  It supports 12V Input.  This is from their spec page saying the outputs are only the USB-A and the images with the USB-C labeled as an "IN1"

If what you are looking at is the USB C power delivery spec that allows laptops to charge over USB C connector, how a device goes about negotiating that is part of the standard rather than 'proprietary,' although which profiles (particularly custom ones) a device supports and how may be.

[How does a USB C port provide the power to charge laptops?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/159552/how-does-a-usb-c-port-provide-the-power-to-charge-laptops)

Comment: Yes, for powerbanks with PD or QC suport it's easier, therefore is here my question for non standard Mi powerbank :)

Comment: how do you know that "this powerbank support 12V" and it is NOT using the PD method?

Comment: https://www.mi.com/global/10000mAh-mi-18w-fast-charge-power-bank-3/specs
PD or QC is not mentioned

Answer (score -1):

If you use 5v charger for charging the powebank, it will give 5v as output. if you use 9v/12v charger for charging the powebank, it will give 9v/12v as output.