# Type-c device for smartphone with optional charging

Tags: usb-device, usb-c, smartphones

I've been challenged to "make" an accessory around [this gps module](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/15136). The idea being to receive the GPS through the serial port emulated into the phone whilst being able to optionally power the GPS module and the phone with an external charger.

I'm new into this and I could gather that with usb 2.0 and microusb connector it would be a matter of switching the ID pin from shorted to ground to a >100kOhm pulldown resistor for the phone to switch between sourcing power to the GPS module to receive any available power.

After reading about the CC1 and CC2 pins on the Type-C connector and looking at the GPS module breakout schematic I'd like to know

- What changes would need to be done in order to use a USB Type-C interface
- Do I need any "fancy" hardware to use USB-C at 5 volts?

Comment: Please ask a specific question

Comment: USB-C has (or should have :-) ) a startup mode that delivers 5V at up to 900 mA. Anything beyong that is arranged by negotiation. While it is possible to DIY the complete inforface this is a very non-trivial task and almost everything I've seen using USB-C in DIY utilises existing control devices. || [This SS EE post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/159605/3288) may help, and [this](https://www.cui.com/blog/usb-type-c-pd-and-pps) CUI inc page seems more practically useful than many. ...

Comment: ... . After that [this Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=usb-c+5+volt+power&rlz=1C1CHBF_enNZ834NZ839&oq=usb-c+5+volt+power&aqs=chrome..69i57j33i22i29i30l7.6295j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) has lots of relevance.